# Android registerReceiver(null, Intent) to get lastest broadcasted values?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

using registerReceiver() by passing a null receiver can be used to get certain system properties.  In the case of my own application broadcasts will this also work. Can I use this same mechanism to get the last broadcasted Intent?

Also how do I know if this Intent was actually processed by a receiver in my application. Do I need for the receiver to issue a confirmation broadcast or is there some way of knowing that the broadcast was fully handled by my application?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found out that sending using sendStickyBroadcast should work for this.  Still need to know if the Intent you get back on registering null receiver was really processed? What do you know for sure about this returned value.